# How to upgrade tomcat version built in WSO2 API Manager v1.10.0?

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2

In the process of using WSO2 API Mananger 1.10.0, I scanned out security vulnerabilities. These vulnerabilities occurred on tomcat. The currently embedded version of tomcat is 7.0.59. I want to know how to upgrade this tomcat to solve these security vulnerabilities, such as upgrading the version to 7.0.93 ... I tried to change the pom.xml of product-apim.  The version of carbon.kernel.version was updated from 4.4.3 to 4.4.37, but there were new problems in the packaging process. I don't know whether I should update the variables of carbon.commons.version, carbon.registry.version, etc. at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be upgrading the tomcat version directly as you are doing.
Your `WSO2-APIM` is very old version which is 1.10.

At that time that tomcat `7.0.59` version was used by wso2. It's better to upgrade your `WSO2-APIM` to latest `2.1.0` version. Here is the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#ffc1cec53fd040c7bfb03dfd17efcc5d) for the same.